# Jquery $(this).text() doesn't return full text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing one problem with jQuery. I want to get text of span tag and set as a tooltip of an image element. Using `$(this).text()` I can see the full text when use Alert and works fine. Now when I hover mouse on image it doesn't show the text after space and if there is any leading space it doesn't show anything. Please see the below example.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("span[id*='name']").each(function(){
            var telValue=$(this).text();
            alert(telValue);
            $(this).after("<img title=" +telValue+" src='path'" ); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>

<span title="FirstNAME" id="Fname" style="width: 100%;" f2="C;40"> First Name is test</span>
```

Comment: Please edit your question with a [mcve] and re-read [ask]. You need to show what you expect, and what you're actually seeing.

Comment: Also, you have some syntax errors in your example. `$("span[id*='name'])` is missing the closing `"` and `}.` is missing a closing `);`.

Comment: first of all why do you provide same id to all spans?

Comment: Sounds like more like an HTML problem. Show the html markup

Comment: @SandipPatel: `id*='name'` means the ID *contains* `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below JS with example

```js
$("span[id*='name']").each(function() {
var Value=$(this).text();
 
  alert(Value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span id="name1"> test 1</span>
<span id="name2"> test 2</span>
<span id="name3"> test 3</span>
```

Comment: Why? How does this solve the OP's issue that hasn't even been explained. This just looks like another "works for me" answer. It's super that your code works for you, but the OP's code does not work for the OP.

Comment: @squint I think here we are helping for others and that is what I am doing sometime people are not able to explain the question but if we understand and if we can provide the answer for that I think that could help them to go ahead and solve the problem...

Comment: Also I as a developer we know sometime we stuck with a small issues and spend lots of time on that other people can solve that quickly so it's better if you are stuck then good to post here

Comment: How does posting a different, working code example help someone with code that doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. Actually Alert display full text but when I bind the same variable as a tooltip to another image element then it doesn't show full text on mouse hover.

Comment: @ROhitKUmar: There's nothing like that shown in your question.

Comment: @ROhitKUmar I think you need to increase the width of tooltip background section I think it will start showing

Comment: @ROhitKUmar can you please provide some of your code

Comment: I edited my question I check the text in Alert and it display full text but when I set same as tooltip to another image element then it doesn't show the full text. I don't know If I'm missing something here.

Comment: Here is the Code I'm using
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$("span[id*='name']").each(function(){var Value=$(this).text();
alert(Value); // This works fine it seems
$(this).after("<img title=" +Value+" style='margin: 0px; border: currentColor; left: 0px; top: 0px;width: 16px; height: 16px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: middle;float:none; display: inline; white-space: nowrap; position: static !important;'src='image.png'>" ); }); }); </script>

<span title="Firstname" id="fname" style="width: 100%;" f2="C;40">First Name test</span>